# What mechanics dictate how fast mongodb releases a lock

Tags: c, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm trying to understand what limits the speed at which mongodb releases locks. Specifically, which system resource should be the bottleneck and why?

I recently had a mongo instance (v2.6.9 w/ replica set) that was experiencing high locking (>100% on a certain db) that was degrading performance. In trying to investigate the root cause, I looked at a lot of different system stats thinking I might find a bottleneck. Interestingly, none of the CPUs on the machine were close to 100%, the memory is not being fully used, and there's no large amount of io wait or disk usage spike.

After much investigation I found the problem - running $addToSet on a large array - however I'm still trying to get stronger intuition about how locks work.

Specifically, which system resource should I be seeing maxed out? If there aren't any parts of the system maxed out, why can't the locks go faster? I expect that if mongo were trying to malloc, I'd see a spike of CPU usage and kernel activity. If it were frantically searching through (or building) an index I'd see CPU usage and maybe growing memory. If I were waiting on replication, I'd see IO waiting. If it were trying to serialize to disk, I'd probably see CPU and disk usage. So what's left?

Comment: There doesn't have to be any correlation between resource usage and locking time. Finely-grained locking doesn't happen automatically, somebody has to spend time and effort to come up with a high performance locking scheme and implement it (hopefully correctly). If your usecase is unusual, it's possible nobody has bothered optimizing it yet.

Comment: How could there not be a correlation between resource usage and locking time? Whether the locking is high performance and optimized or not, I would think the limiting factor should be a system resource at some level.

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock(&global_lock); sleep(5000); pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_lock);`.

Comment: If it *was* actual code, wouldn't somebody go and fix it?

Comment: MongoDB is the root cause. Time to switch to another DB that wouldn't need locking. *MVCC \*cough\**